# My car won't start but everything else works

Tags: battery, starting, chevrolet, trailblazer

Car won't start but everything else works fine I tired everything is stuck n gear

Comment: Could you please add more details so we can help you solving the problem?

Comment: Do you own this car?  Are you using the key? Is there gas in it? Is the battery charged? What kind of car is it? Is there an alarm?

Comment: No do not own it yes I'm using the key when I turn the key all my lights cum own so I no is not the battery is a Chevy trail blazer 4200 engine yes it has gas

Comment: Have you attempted a jump start? Sounds like your battery is just dead. Dash lights/radio/etc. coming on doesn't indicate a healthy battery.

Comment: No I have not did that yet it did this before but that time my lights n stuff was not coming on I will try that n see thank you for your help

Comment: Just to expand on @justinm410 's answer: dash lights and the radio use very little battery power, but turning the engine over uses a friggin lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an automatic gearbox?  If it is and it's stuck in gear, the starter won't trigger because an auto will only spin the start in P or N.

If it's a manual, depress the clutch as without the clutch pressed in, with the car in gear, the starter is trying to turn the engine, gearbox, wheels (and presumably act against the e-brake).